# What are major differences between actual Ubuntu and Ubuntu Kylin?

Tags: kylin

I am interested in knowing the stuffs about Linux,From last 8 months i am addicted with Ubuntu Versions, but still i don't know the difference between actual Ubuntu and Ubuntu Kylin. please give me clear understanding between those two. Is Ubuntu Kylin is available only in chinese language? If not so please give me the latest LTS version of Ubuntu Kylin which can be usable in India. Is it safe for use? and i also curious about differences between different Ubuntu Versions other than normal releases.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> *Ubuntu Kylin is an official flavour of Ubuntu. It is a free PC operating system created for China and complies with the Chinese Government procurement regulations. It includes all the features you’ve come to expect from Ubuntu, alongside essential Chinese software and apps. The interface has been designed specifically to put Chinese users first — and with new support for touch screens and HiDPI monitors, it runs beautifully on all kinds of hardware.*

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin